# Unresolved external symbol xxx referenced in function TestMockedTRHUStart(void) using MS Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, linker

I have a real exe application, which is basically class trhu.  I created a test harness class mocktrhu which inherits from trhu and overrides some functions in trhu.

These 2 projects are part of a Visual Studio 2012 C++ (unmanaged/native) solution.

Both exe projects in the solution build without problems.

I then created a VC++ Test, Native Unit Test Project with tests for both the reaal application and the mocked application.  Strangely, the test for the real application builds ok, but for the mocked application I get an unresolved reference error LNK2019.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TRHUUnitTests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  TRHUUnitTests.cpp
1>     Creating library \MyAppUnderTest_SO\Debug\TRHUUnitTests.lib and object \MyAppUnderTest_SO\Debug\TRHUUnitTests.exp
1>TRHUUnitTests.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall mocktrhu::mocktrhu(class config const &)" (??0mocktrhu@@QAE@ABVconfig@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TRHUUnitTests::UnitTests::TestMockedTRHUStart(void)" (?TestMockedTRHUStart@UnitTests@TRHUUnitTests@@QAEXXZ)
1>TRHUUnitTests.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall mocktrhu::start(void)" (?start@mocktrhu@@UAE_NXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TRHUUnitTests::UnitTests::TestMockedTRHUStart(void)" (?TestMockedTRHUStart@UnitTests@TRHUUnitTests@@QAEXXZ)
1>\MyAppUnderTest_SO\Debug\TRHUUnitTests.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The Problem unit test is:

```
TEST_METHOD(TestMockedTRHUStart)
{
    // test mocked TRHU startup
    const int comport(3);
    config conf(comport);
    mocktrhu trhu1(conf);
    trhu1.start();
}
```

Here is the code:

Unit test code, TRHUUnitTests.cpp :-

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "application.hpp"
#include "MyAppTestHarness.hpp"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace TRHUUnitTests
{       
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTests)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMockedTRHUStart)
        {
            // test mocked TRHU startup
            const int comport(3);
            config conf(comport);
            mocktrhu trhu1(conf);
            trhu1.start();
        }
        TEST_METHOD(TestRealTRHUStart)
        {
            // test mocked TRHU startup - NOTE: requires connection to real hardware
            const int comport(3);
            config conf(comport);
            trhu trhu1(conf);
            trhu1.start();
        }
    };
}
```

The real application code (unit test works for this - application.hpp):

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_HPP_
#define APPLICATION_HPP_

#include <iostream>

class config
{
public:
    config(int comport) : comport_(comport) {}

    int getport() const { return comport_; }

private:
    int comport_;
};

class trhu
{
public:
    trhu(const config& configuration) : config_(configuration) {}

    virtual bool start()
    {
        // open com port - real hardware stuff
        std::cout << "tchu program opening com port " << config_.getport() << '\n';
        return true;
    }
protected:
    config config_;
};

#endif // APPLICATION_HPP_
```

Real application code implementation (application.cpp):

```
#include "application.hpp"

int main() {
    const int comport(3);
    config conf(comport);
    trhu trhu1(conf);
    trhu1.start();
}
```

Mocked app (unit test linker error - MyAppTestHarness.hpp):

```
#ifndef MYAPPTESTHARNESS_HPP_
#define MYAPPTESTHARNESS_HPP_

#include "application.hpp"

class mocktrhu : public trhu
{
public:
    mocktrhu(const config& configuration);
    virtual bool start();
};

#endif // MYAPPTESTHARNESS_HPP_
```

Mocked application code implementation (MyAppTestHarness..cpp):

```
#include "MyAppTestHarness.hpp"

#include <iostream>

mocktrhu::mocktrhu(const config& configuration)
    : trhu(configuration) {}

bool mocktrhu::start()
{
    // open com port - real hardware stuff
    std::cout << "mocked tchu program opening com port: " << config_.getport()      '\n';
    return true;
}

int main() {
    const int comport(3);
    config conf(comport);
    mocktrhu trhu1(conf);
    trhu1.start();
}
```

For completeness project and solution files:

By the way I have only configured the Debug project so only look at the Debug project.

Solution:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "MyAppUnderTest", "MyAppUnderTest\MyAppUnderTest.vcxproj", "{F8EE9D1D-AA29-4B38-A579-7449C658EB7C}"
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "MyAppTestHarness", "MyAppTestHarness\MyAppTestHarness.vcxproj", "{9052E9B6-FE19-4C76-B7E6-0BE44D0914AD}"
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "TRHUUnitTests", "TRHUUnitTests\TRHUUnitTests.vcxproj", "{D745B2BA-930F-43ED-A9DC-04FABE031F01}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
        Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {F8EE9D1D-AA29-4B38-A579-7449C658EB7C}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {F8EE9D1D-AA29-4B38-A579-7449C658EB7C}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {9052E9B6-FE19-4C76-B7E6-0BE44D0914AD}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {9052E9B6-FE19-4C76-B7E6-0BE44D0914AD}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {D745B2BA-930F-43ED-A9DC-04FABE031F01}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {D745B2BA-930F-43ED-A9DC-04FABE031F01}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Unit test project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{D745B2BA-930F-43ED-A9DC-04FABE031F01}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>TRHUUnitTests</RootNamespace>
    <ProjectName>TRHUUnitTests</ProjectName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\include;../MyAppUnderTest;../MyAppTestHarness;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <UseFullPaths>true</UseFullPaths>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <UseFullPaths>true</UseFullPaths>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="TRHUUnitTests.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Main app project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{F8EE9D1D-AA29-4B38-A579-7449C658EB7C}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>MyAppUnderTest</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>NotSet</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="application.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="application.hpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Test harness project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{9052E9B6-FE19-4C76-B7E6-0BE44D0914AD}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>MyAppTestHarness</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>NotSet</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>../MyAppUnderTest</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="MyAppTestHarness.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="MyAppTestHarness.hpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

I noticed that I put the implementation of the code which works, trhu class, in the header file.  If I do the same for the test harness mock code then it links ok.  ie like this:

```
#ifndef MYAPPTESTHARNESS_HPP_
#define MYAPPTESTHARNESS_HPP_

#include "application.hpp"

class mocktrhu : public trhu
{
public:
    mocktrhu(const config& configuration)
    : trhu(configuration) {}

    virtual bool start()
    {
        // open com port - real hardware stuff
        std::cout << "mocked tchu program opening com port: " << config_.getport() << '\n';
        return true;
    }
};

#endif // MYAPPTESTHARNESS_HPP_
```

But of course that is not what I want.  I want to separate header from implementation in real code.

Is it because applications are exe and not libs?  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

UPDATE2:

Possibly to get this to work I need to put the mocks in the unit test project?

UPDATE3:

I am thinking now that to use the unit test  project I need to change from implementing real app and mocks as exes to instead implement as libraries so that I can use the libs in the unit test project.  Any feedback from people using MS unit testing framework.  What do you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to call a function from MS Test framework you need to be able to link the MS Test project with the object code for the function (or object or whatever).  In the example above the 'real' application code implementation was all in the header file so didn't pose a problem.  In the mocked application code, the implementation code was not in a header file so in this case was not available to the MS Test project.  Hence the linker error.

The problem is that you cannot test code where you cannot link in the object code.  The real and mock projects were executable type.  You could try linking with the intermediate object files generated from the builds but that would maybe not be a clean solution.

I fixed the problem by changing the design a little.  I put the real and mock code into libraries.  So the real application is still an exe project but it uses a library which implements the program logic.  so the unit test project can link with this library.  The same goes for the mock project - it was changed to be a library.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find implementation of `mocktrhu::mocktrhu(class config const &)` in your code (only declaration). Where is it implemented?

Comment: I assume `MyAppTestHarness..cpp` file may not be added to the build properly... But I cannot check this from the xml files because I am not a big expert in VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0):

You have no method body definition in MyAppTestHarness.cpp.
Also, you may need to [export](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx) your class to use it in other project.

Comment: I forgot to include - edited now - see above.  Problem seems to be that if I have implementation file, the unit testing project can't link - because has no access to object file (it is in exe) and so doesn't work.  Also I can't export because myapptestharness is an exe. I think I need to put the mocks in the unit test project.

Comment: You make all methods of "mocktrhu" class inline (e.g. write definitions in header).
Or, you can extract this class to another DLL and use it in both projects.
Or, as you noted, put the mocks in the unit test project.

Comment: Yes realise I can do that now to fix immediate problem, but not a good solution.  I think you can only unit test dlls or libs.  Which is fine.  so I have to put main code logic in libs and use from exe.  But then I can unit test.